# " If $f$ -$g$ are integrable over [a,b] then f and g are integrable over [a,b] ?"

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

If $f$ :[a,b] $ \rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ and $g$ :[a,b] $ \rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ are bounded functions. Can anyone please give a counterexample of the following statement :

" If $f$ -$g$ are integrable over [a,b] then f and g are integrable over [a,b] "

I already prove by counterexample that it doesnt happens always that    $f$+ $g$ or  $fg$ integrable over [a,b] then $f$ and $g$ are integrable with the functions $f$ and $g$ defined as  f(x)= { 0 if x is rational and 1 if x is irrational} and g(x) ={ 1 if x is rational and 0 if x is irrational} but they dont seem to work to prove in the given statement. Thanks

Comment: Try to think of $f-g = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $f$ any function you like and let $g(x)=f(x)-1$. The function $f-g$ is just the constant $1$. and therefore is integrable  but we can in no way conclude $f$ is integrable.